# Javascript Facebook Variables Issue

Tags: javascript, facebook

Ok, so I know Javascript and have been piecing together a small app for Facebook.  The problem is somewhere between my JS and the facebook api.

I used the standard library to populate an array with a users friend list and display them for choosing.

```
function renderMFS() {
// First get the list of friends for this user with the Graph API
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
    var container = document.getElementById('mfs');
    var mfsForm = document.createElement('form');
    mfsForm.id = 'mfsForm';

    // Iterate through the array of friends object and create a checkbox for each one.
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(response.data.length, 1000); i++) {
        var friendItem = document.createElement('div');
        friendItem.id = 'friend_' + response.data[i].id;
        friendItem.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" onclick="sendSlap(this)" name="friends" value="' + response.data[i].id + '" />' + response.data[i].name;

        mfsForm.appendChild(friendItem);

    }

    container.appendChild(mfsForm);
    });
```

}

And then I used a function of my own to post two feed messages.

```
function sendSlap(cb) {



FB.ui({
    method : 'feed',
    link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/537130286376086',
    to : cb.value,
    description : 'You have been bitch slapped by a friend',
    actions: [
        {'name': 'Slap Back', 'link': 'https://apps.facebook.com/537130286376086'}
        ],
}, function(response) {
});

FB.ui({
    method : 'feed',
    link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/537130286376086',
    description: "Someone just got bitch slapped",
    actions: [
        {'name': 'Slap Someone!', 'link': 'https://apps.facebook.com/537130286376086'}
        ],
}, function(response) {
});
```

}

All of this works just fine.  The problem is when I try to bring actual data into the "posts".  My first approach did not work and there was not an error, it simply did not produce a post.

```
description: "Someone just got bitch slapped" + cb.name,
```

As you can see, the var "cb" carries with it the data from the call.  cb.value works just fine and it is called to in the same manner and what I am trying to do.  But, rather than get too deep into that I quickly created a separate function that would pull the information I needed.

```
FB.api(cb.value, function(response) {

    var data1=response.name;
            return data1;


    }
```

I used alerts to check that both cb.value was coming through just fine and that response.name was correct and I checked spelling on all the data.  I then pulled data1 back into the post and got "undefined" in the posting.  I fiddled with this several ways and it just does not bring back data.  The first approach made the most sense, but there is something seriously wrong here.

Comment: Not suer I get it right, but shouldn't you `FB.api(cb,function(response)` (`cb` not `cb.value`)? And don't b'slap me if I am wrong ;)

Comment: That was what I tried originally and it does not work for whatever reason.  I used two alerts to verify the data that was produced and the call to FB.api does produce a name and userID, but the information never makes it out of the function in the return.

Comment: What I am looking at more and more is the original call.  The code floating on the internet to create a "friend selector" uses the "id" of the friend to create the individual divs and there is no reason for that per se.  I believe that I can add a tag there somewhere to bring the extra information over in the first call.

Comment: Using the original call, I solved half the problem.  In the first function I changed the "name" from "friends" to response.data[i].name.  That made it easier to pull that data from the first function.  The fact is that the function was sending a "div" and all of its information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the original call, I solved half the problem. In the first function I changed the "name" from "friends" to response.data[i].name. That made it easier to pull that data from the first function. The fact is that the function was sending a "div" and all of its information.

Comment: I am going to go with this for the moment, although I am sure that the FB api has some easier and more efficient way to include the "sender" and the "poster" in a feed post.

Answer (score 1):

morantis, I have a built application and had some of these issues, I solved it by using  FB.getLoginStatus with an access token, and when needed fb.ui inside these functions, it gave me full functionality within my app, and full control to all that data you are getting from user. 
also using global Objects, did the trick with keeping info like feeds.

Comment: here is JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yyvb3/
it goes on alot more, but the idea is the mostly the same.
hope it helps

Comment: It all became very moot.  There are so many ways to accomplish the same process and yet all of them have minor issues with them.  For some odd reason simply inserting the line response.name;  in the function made the results more accessible.  That, of course, led to some pretty slow running functions for no reason at all.  I ran into a snag with the function hanging and needing to be re-init.  In the end, the app was not that important and was more for play than anything.  The interesting thing is that GET formed calls to the graph.api work better than anything.